# Mysql get row number

Tags: mysql, row, row-number

I've a table like this

```
+------+----------+------------+
|   id |  1_value |   2_value  |
+------+----------+------------+
|    3 |   foo1   |   other    |
|   10 |   fooX   |   stuff    |
|   13 |   fooJ   |   here     |
|   22 |   foo7   |   and      |
|   31 |   foou   |   here     |
+------+----------+------------+
```

What I want to get is to have the row number

I've tried to do something like this

```
SELECT  id, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    table
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
```

and it work indeed...

```
+------+--------------+
|   id |  row_number  | 
+------+--------------+
|    3 |   1          | 
|   10 |   2          |
|   13 |   3          |
|   22 |   4          |
|   31 |   5          |
+------+--------------+
```

but what if I try to select a specific row?

```
SELECT  id, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    srwk_esp_registration
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
WHERE ID = 22
```

In this case, row_number is 1, but it should be 4.

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with Sub - query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT id,
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
    FROM srwk_esp_registration
    JOIN (
        SELECT @curRow := 0
        ) r
    ) sub
WHERE sub.ID = 22
```

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want to declare a variable (SET @rownum something)...

Normally, my normal query is

```
SELECT t.* FROM ticket t
```

I would add `@i:=@i+1 as row_number,` before or after `t.*` and join the table with `(SELECT @i:=0)`:

```
SELECT @i:=@i+1 as row_number, t.* FROM ticket t, (SELECT @i:=0) AS temp
```

try to alter the sample query and hope it would help.

Good Luck!